# Prove that if $T$ is a tree, then $T \setminus e$ is disconnected

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $T$ is a tree, then $T\setminus e$ (difference) is  disconnected for any $e\in E(T)$.

Someone can help me or give me some hints or refernce for answer this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A graph is connected if there's a path connecting any two distinct vertices.

The endpoints of $e$ are two distinct vertices.

If $T \setminus e$ is connected, then what do we get when we combine a path connecting the endpoints of $e$ with the edge $e$ itself?

Answer (score 3):

For a tree we have the equality $|V| = |E| + 1$.

If $T \setminus e$ were connected, it would be a tree (still no cycles, and connected) but it would violate the equality, as |V| has stayed the same but $|E|$ has decreased by 1.

So $T \setminus e$ must be disconnected.